# boost::filesystem::path and std::string

Tags: c++, boost, path, boost-filesystem

I have a String class which has a member std::string. One of the constructor is

```
String (std::string s)
{
    // member: std::string _mString;
    _mString = s;  // error on path assignment
}
```

I now have functions that take String as parameter, e.g. Load(String path);

but it turns out that boost::filesystem::path::string() is incompatible with that String constructor, yet, normally assigning is ok

```
boost::filesystem::path somepath("some directory")
std::string filename = somepath.extension(); // OK!
```

What is happening? How can I make my constructor work? Thanks.

EDIT: Issue solved by making it const ref, but still curious why the error because it seems ok to pass a copy since it can be assigned directly.
Error in file xstring

```
void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Tidy(bool _Built = false,
        size_type _Newsize = 0)
        {   // initialize buffer, deallocating any storage
        if (!_Built)
            ;
        else if (_BUF_SIZE <= _Myres)
            {   // copy any leftovers to small buffer and deallocate
            _Elem *_Ptr = _Bx._Ptr;
            if (0 < _Newsize)
                _Traits_helper::copy_s<_Traits>(_Bx._Buf, _BUF_SIZE, _Ptr, _Newsize);
            _Mybase::_Alval.deallocate(_Ptr, _Myres + 1);
            }
        _Myres = _BUF_SIZE - 1; // **** ERROR ***
        _Eos(_Newsize);
        }
```

Comment: What does the failing assignment look like?

Comment: Can you post more code and details?

Comment: in your constructor: `String (std::string s)` should be `String (const std::string& s)`

Comment: @Sam there's certainly an efficiency issue there, but why do you say that it _should_ be that way?

Comment: @San in general it's preferable to pass non primitive types as const reference if they are not modified.

Comment: @Sam Miller. Actually i have many constructors for String e.g. String(const Matrix& matrix) and all of them are const references. I don't know why I missed out on this. And it's LOL because that fixed my problem.

Comment: However, it still begs the question why there would be an error. Because it seems ok to pass a copy since it can be assigned directly. but somehow, it is lost-in-transit error in <xstring>

Comment: @Jake very odd indeed. I've added my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Sam fair enough; I wasn't very clear. I was wondering if your prescription had anything to do with the error at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your constructor: `String (std::string s)` should be `String (const std::string& s)`